# How do I get IntelliJ to recognise resource bundle when compiling?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jenkins-plugins

Ok, first up I am almost completely unfamiliar with Java and Java tooling.

I am attempting to contribute a bugfix to a Jenkins [plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/copyartifact-plugin).  Code-wise the fix is simple, my problem is in trying to compile the project and run the tests locally.

I have installed IntelliJ IDEA 15CE and started a new project, pointing it to my local clone of the plugin repo.

It has gone away and 'downloaded the internet' in terms of Maven dependencies. Mostly everything looks ok. What I want to do is to run the tests...

If I right-click at the root of the project and select 'Run All Tests' I get the error:

```
Error:(115, 29) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Messages
  location: class hudson.plugins.copyartifact.BuildSelector
```

The source of this error is a line:

```
 console.println(Messages.CopyArtifact_MissingSrcArtifacts(srcDir));
```

https://github.com/jenkinsci/copyartifact-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/copyartifact/BuildSelector.java#L115

As far as I can tell the `Messages` symbol should resolve to this properties file:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/copyartifact-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/copyartifact/Messages.properties
...which IDEA recognises as a 'Resource Bundle' in the project tree view.

But it doesn't seem to recognise it when compiling the project.

I have no idea where to start fixing this. The tests run fine if I push a commit to a pull request on GitHub and let the cloudbees.com Jenkins server run them, but I'd like to be able to test stuff locally first.

Answer (score 6):

Run the maven compile command from Intelli-J Maven  tool. After compiling error will vanish.
When you compile it will generate a Messages.java file in generated sources automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't add an image by commenting on the response of @mnpoonia, I added this second answer that builds on his by adding the following:

In order to have proper Intellij integration after mvn compile, you can mark "generated-sources" as type "sources" in Intellij -> Project Settings -> Modules -> your module -> see image. Afterwards that Messages class will work properly in Intellij, it will be found and Intellij will be happy.

Could also add mvn compile as a before step for other types of jobs executed from Intellij, like JUnit and so on if necessary. This way that Messages java file will always be created.

[image]